# What is the logical difference between "to seek" and "to look for"?

Tags: differences, verbs

I have seen a non-native English speaker write "Still seeking for a job". That got me thinking, what is the difference between *to seek* and *look for*?

Comment: You do realize "seeking for" isn't grammatical, right?

Comment: "To seek" and "to look for" are exact synonyms.  No difference.  But I think you realise that you shouldn't use "for" after "seek".

Comment: I didn't know that, but wouldn't use it that way either due to "gut feeling". I am still more interested in the difference between two verbs though.

Comment: @David, if verbs are synonyms, why one can't `seek for` something?

Comment: @David Wallace: Hmm. The OED has 104 citations that include 'seek for'.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Hah!  Of course it does!  I had better retract my last comment then.

Comment: @Barrie: I haven't bothered to look at the 104 citations (yet), but I still agree with David in that _seek for_ does sound "off" in some contexts, like "still seeking for a job."  (Now, I might say, "I'll seek for awhile, and if I haven't found anything by tomorrow...")

Comment: @J.R.It certainly isn’t common. 64 records in the COCA against 1557 for ‘look for’, with equivalent figures of 30 and 2192 in the BNC! But I always question 'shouldn't'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the applicant is using a telephone to seek employment?

This would be considered seeking but not literally looking.

In a non-literal sense, "looking for" is synonymous with "sniffing out" but I don't think you can use that to argue that these terms are synonymous in every other context in which one of them might be used.

Logically, seeking encompasses a greater variety of methods and senses than does looking.

Comment: do "seek out" and "look for" mean the same thing?

Answer (score 11):

I regard them as synonyms. However, there is a lexical difference. 'Seek' is a pure verb and 'look for' is a phrasal verb - a pure verb plus, in this case, a preposition. Phrasal verbs carry an idiomatic meaning and are more typical in spoken or informal usage.

A similar pair might be 'discover' and 'find out' - but we would never think to transfer the preposition from the phrasal verb and use it with the pure verb - 'discover out'.

Comment: Actually, _look for_ is not a phrasal verb like _look up_, but rather a transitivizing preposition like _look at_ or _listen to_. The difference is that transitive phrasal verbs alternate NP objects, but not transitivizing verbs: _He looked up the word, He looked the word up, He looked for the word,_ but not *_He looked the word for_.

Answer (score -1):

The general difference in usage is "seek" is used for something untangible whereas "look for" is used for something concrete.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, phoebe. I suppose some would regard the Scarlet Pimpernel as intangible. But Job 30:26 (NKJV) reads :'But when I looked for good, evil came to me' [[BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/kjv/job/30-26.htm)].