# what is the difference between "seek" or "search" ?

Tags: meaning

Can I use a verb seek in this way "makes me seek more rewarding and challenging environment"? 
Thank you

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35507/seek-vs-search look here

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that seek is a *transitive* verb, while search is an *intransitive* verb. So seek can take a direct object (eg. "I seek money"), while search can't - eg. you can't say "I search money", you have to add the word *for* - so "I search for money" would be correct.

In your example, you can definitely use *seek*, just don't forget to add the article "a" before "more rewarding and challenging environment." You could also use *search*, but you should add *want to* before *search* - *Makes me want to search for a more rewarding and challenging environment.* (It's more idiomatic that way, because the thing you're describing probably isn't physically making you "search for" a different environment).